# How to re-group a bar graph by specific groups and order of frequency

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart

I have a dataset that I am trying to group and plot a certain way. I've included an example here:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Sample = c("PT1", "PT2", "PT3", "PT4", "PT5", "PT6", "PT7", "PT8", "PT9", "PT10"),
              Genotype = c("AA/BB", "AA/CC", "BB/CC", "AA/DD", "AA/AA", "BB/CC", "BB/DD", "CC/DD", "BB/BB", "AA/DD"),
              Phenotype = c("Red", "Blue", "Pink", "Blue", "Blue", "Pink", "Pink", "White", "Red", "Blue"))
```

I am trying to plot the genotypes in a specific order that I specify (by phenotype) and order of frequency.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

df2 <- df1[c(2,3)] %>%
  table() %>% #Gives the frequency count of the genotypes
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>% #needed in order to use the arrange function (which doesn't work on tables)
  arrange(desc(Freq)) %>% #sorts by largest to smallest
  filter(Freq > 0) %>% #Remove genotypes with 0 counts
  group_by(Phenotype) %>% #Sorts by phenotype
  mutate(Phenotype=fct_relevel(Phenotype,c("Blue","Red","Pink", "White"))) #Reorder factor levels

#Make the plot
ggplot(df2, aes(x=str_wrap(Genotype,5), y=Freq, fill=Phenotype)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  theme_pubr() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270, vjust = 1, hjust = 1, size = 7),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
  xlab("Genotypes by order of phenotype and freq") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue","red", "pink", "white"))
```

Which gives the following plot:
[image]

I would like the plot to be ordered by **highest freq** to **lowest freq** *and* follow the Phenotype order I specified (Blue, Red, Pink, and White). Any idea how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update after OP request: Removed prior answer:

Here we first manipulate the data an bring in the order we want to plot. Then we use `fct_inorder`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(Phenotype = factor(Phenotype, levels = c("Blue", "Red", "Pink", "White"))) %>% 
  add_count(Genotype) %>% 
  arrange(Phenotype, -n) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=fct_inorder(Genotype), y=n, fill=Phenotype)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  theme_pubr() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270, vjust = 1, hjust = 1, size = 7),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
  xlab("Genotypes by order of phenotype and freq") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue","red", "pink", "white"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi TarJae, 

Thanks, this is helpful to organize by frequency! Do you know of any way to group all the blues, reds, pinks, and whites together as well so that it's ordered by frequency and grouped by color?

Comment: just change the arrange line to : ` arrange(Phenotype, -n) %>% `. Please see my update.